# UIView Disappears after pan gesture

Tags: ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I am using the following handler for a IUPanGesture.  However when the pan ends, the UIView that it is moving disappears.  Do I need to add anything else to this code?

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
  if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
  (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {

  CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:[self superview]];

  [self setCenter:location];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's documented anywhere, but I've found empirically that any gesture states other than `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`, `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`, and `UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized` will have garbage touch and location information. In many cases, the code would even crash trying to access a non-existent touch.

So, changing the condition as follows should fix the issue you're having:

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
  if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:[self superview]];
    [self setCenter:location];
  }
}
```